# What does this C macro mean?

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

Looking at [fm_transmitter](https://github.com/markondej/fm_transmitter/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=ACCESS) source code, I came across this macro, which is used quite often.

```
#define ACCESS(base, offset) *(volatile unsigned*)((int)base + offset)
```

I guess its a sum of base and offset casted as int, then re-casted into unsigned pointer and then again pointer?

Comment: Yes, that appears to be exactly what the code says.

Comment: Well then why don't just (unsigned*)(base + offset)?

Comment: This interprets `base` as `int` adds `offset`, interprets this as a pointer to `unsigned`, and then dereferences it. This is very ugly and non-portable because generally `int` isn't large enough to hold pointer values.

Comment: The first `*` dereferences the pointer, so that the expression accesses the intended memory location.  Presumably `volatile` is used to indicate that this is a hardware memory-mapped value that may change "by itself" and so the compiler should not cache the result

Comment: Your linked example is C++ and does not show how the macro is used.

Comment: @Horkyze, we can't know that, because you didn't show us type which the `base` has when it is called in the code.

Comment: that is a reinterpret cast `*(volatile unsigned*)`

Comment: Hi. I'm an RF guy. Please don't use this code in the wild without proper output filtering (mainly, low passing). Toggling Pins on and off leads to **strong** out-of-band emissions, in regular intervals, because the signal shape is a rectangular "wave", the spectrum of that is a sinc (=(sin x)/x), which means it has sidelobes all over the place. You might get into trouble with your local authorities, even.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This macro provides access to an offset that is measured in bytes. You could rewrite it as

```
#define ACCESS(base, offset) *(volatile unsigned*)&((char*)base)[offset]
```

only that the original version does the arithmetic via the `int` type instead of the `char*` type.

Note that use of this macro likely invokes undefined behavior: The resulting pointer is not guaranteed to be properly aligned, and if the data was written as some other type than an `int` variant, it's a violation of strict aliasing rules as well.

Also, the choice of `int` to do the pointer arithmetic is a very poor choice, the calculation should at least be done via `size_t` or `uintptr_t` to guarantee that the pointer is not truncated during the cast to the integer type. My rewritten version does not have this specific problem, however, the danger of undefined behavior remains with both versions.

Finally, as Olaf rightly noted in the comments, it's also a bad idea to cast to `volatile unsigned*` since the width of this type is implementation defined. A cast to `volatile uint32_t*` would likely be more appropriate for communication with hardware.

Comment: Indeed it is very poor as a choice and shouldn't be done at all with integer arithmetic. Something along the line that you propose is far better because you don't have to figure out what the correct integer type would be.

Comment: So to put it in simple terms, this macro 'returns' the value which is stored at base+offset?

Comment: Not only using `int` for the address-arithmetic is poor, but - as it does generate an absolute address to (very likely) some hardware register, it should point to a fixed-width integer. If there are already such flaws, I would not trust the rest of the code much.

Comment: @Horkyze: Yes, irrespective of whether `base` is a `char`, a `long`, a `void*`, or a `foo*`. That's a big part of the danger connected with this macro.

Comment: @Olaf Right. I added a paragraph on this. Thank you, for pointing this out.